# В сумме или на сумму?

Tags: лексика

"Данные явились основанием для получения средств в сумме (на сумму), превышающей (-ую) допустимые размеры".

Когда употребляются эти варианты или же они равнозначны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, надо знать, о чем идет речь. Если "в сумме", то мы подразумеваем, что все средства сложили и некий арифметический результат получили *в сумме*. А если "на сумму", то речь уже идет о том, сколько денег получили на руки.
Может, я не совсем понятно объясняю. Скажем так, в первом случае предполагаются некие математические действия.

Comment: То есть в приведенном мной случае все же НА сумму?